# Isolation Level for stored procedure SQL Server?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, isolation-level

I want to add Isolation level in my procedure and for that I wanted to confirm that which one is the correct format from below:

Attempt #1 - setting isolation level before calling the stored procedure:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

EXEC [sp_GetProductDetails] 'ABCD','2017-02-20T11:51:37.3178768'
```

Attempt #2 - setting isolation level inside the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP AS
BEGIN
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
   BEGIN TRAN 
       SELECT * FROM MyTable
       SELECT * FROM MyTable2
       SELECT * FROM MyTable3

       COMMIT TRAN  
END
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both versions are "correct" - they just do **different things**:

- Your attempt #1 sets the isolation level for that database and connection - that means, the chosen isolation level will be used for any future statement - until you change the isolation level again
- Your attempt #2 sets the isolation level **only INSIDE the stored procedure** - so once the stored procedure is completed, the isolation level that existed on the database/connection level is restored again

So it really depends on what you want to do:

- set the isolation level to a different level **in general** for your current connection to this database? Any future statement will be run under this isolation level --> choose #1
- set the isolation level to a different setting for just a single stored procedure - regardless of what the connnection/database had before - then use #2

Answer (score -1):

`ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` is default ISOLATION for SQL database.

**Attempt #2** is good practice to set `ISOLATION LEVEL`.